# What's this third argument to PostgreSQL `tstzrange`?

Tags: postgresql, range-types

On https://www.timescale.com/blog/best-practices-for-time-series-metadata-tables/ there's a function declaration that looks for time range overlaps with:

```sql
SELECT NOT isempty(
        tstzrange(rangeStart, rangeEnd) *
        tstzrange(series.ts_start, series.ts_end, '[]')
    );
```

When I [search the PostgreSQL docs for tstzrange](https://www.postgresql.org/search/?u=%2Fdocs%2F16%2F&q=tstzrange) I find only 1 mention of it as a data type and none as a function.

What's that `[]` argument doing, and is it documented somewhere?

Comment: constructors are described in general here, including the 3 argument form: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT):

> Each range type has a constructor function with the same name as the range type. Using the constructor function is frequently more convenient than writing a range literal constant, since it avoids the need for extra quoting of the bound values. The constructor function accepts two or three arguments. The two-argument form constructs a range in standard form (lower bound inclusive, upper bound exclusive), while the three-argument form constructs a range with bounds of the form specified by the third argument. The third argument must be one of the strings “`()`”, “`(]`”, “`[)`”, or “`[]`”. For example:
>
> ```
> -- The full form is: lower bound, upper bound, and text argument indicating
> -- inclusivity/exclusivity of bounds.
> SELECT numrange(1.0, 14.0, '(]');
> ```